# Kruskal Wallis Test: Sample Size Difference

Tags: sample-size, kruskal-wallis-test

I would like to run a Kruskal Wallis test. There are 5 groups that I need to compare.

```
Group 1 Sample Size: 37
Group 2 Sample Size: 33
Group 3 Sample Size: 36
Group 4 Sample Size: 16
Group 5 Sample Size: 172
```

Im concerned with the sample size of the last group.Does it have any effect with the results? A post hoc analysis will be ran if the difference is found significant.

Thanks!

Comment: Your sample number 4 seems quite small, wouldn't that be a concern, too?..

Comment: I thought that is okay. Anyway, what is the  effect of having these small/big sample size?

Comment: I have not encountered this before. Maybe you could try simulations under the null to see how the test works for the particular sample sizes? You could start from just a couple of samples like 37 and 172 or 16 and 172 if dimensionality is a problem.